# Dependency conflict with war in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, war, dependency-management

I have a `tomcat` server with two web applications running. I want to add a `CAS` server. To do so, I'm using the CAS Overlay to produce a `cas.war`. The problem is when I try to add the `cas.war` file to `tomcat/webapps/`, there is a bug arising telling me:

```
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory
[...]
```

My understanding is that there is a dependency conflict concerning `slf4j`. After some investigation, I've noticed that the `slf4j` dependency is in `tomcat/lib/`. Therefore, the conflict comes from this dependency being in `tomcat/lib/` and in `cas.war`.

What is the best thing to do?

- erase `slf4j` from `tomcat/lib/` and put it in each web applications' dependency
- erase `slf4j` from the `cas.war` and the CAS server will take the global `slf4j` dependency

Thanks!

Comment: If your webapp is bundling this as a dependency, it should be present in the WebApp - else it will be picked up from the CATALINA_HOME\lib. Try packing that jar as part of your webapp to see if that helps!

Comment: Too thin for a formal answer, but I recommend switching to using Maven as your build/dependency management tool.  It will automatically handle and resolve these class loading conflicts.